# bootstrap modal, django login_required

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, login-required

I've managed to use bootstrap modal when user click a login button to show a login form.

Now, there is a login_required decorator which renders a login template.
The login_required decorator is server-side code, and I need a way to let the server to tell the client to initiate the button click.

```
$('#myModal').modal('show'); // this shows the form.
```

How can I initiate this call from my server? Or I need to change every client code that could result in the login_required.

Has anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: Well it sure is possible, but you would need to make a hook of some kind, whenever you click any link or button, you would have to make an ajax call to check for permission. Is it something you're ok with?..

Comment: yes, anything fine to make it work!, but how?

Comment: so, it's like, ajax call to check if login is required, and call `modal()` to show the form ? then I guess I can just hard-wire the {% if request.user.is_authenticated %} in every client code that might require a view with login_required.

Comment: and remove the login_required from the view codes. guess it will work.. but not as pretty as the simple login_required.

Comment: You can make a customized ajax decorator like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10031220/1566605)

Comment: you can have a home view, and login view, then in the modal - you are setting content to be loaded via `remote` http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-options or jquery (as per docs)
then you can load form from the login page into modal, but you shouold reload whole page while doing post